# How to get the file's created, modified dates and the kind of the file using NSFileHandle?

Tags: cocoa, nsfilehandle, file-attributes

How to get the file's created, modified dates and the kind of the file using NSFileHandle? 
please help me out with this question.
i tried with NSDate, but dint find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFileHandle` is not the ideal class for this. Is there some reason you want to use that class or feel you have to?

You should use `-[NSURL getResourceValue:forKey:error:]` with the keys `NSURLCreationDateKey`, `NSURLContentModificationDateKey`, and `NSURLTypeIdentifierKey`.

If you really only have an `NSFileHandle` to go on, you will have to obtain its file descriptor using the `-fileDescriptor` method and then the `fstat()` function to obtain the creation and modification times. You can use `fcntl()` with `F_GETPATH` to recover the path from a file descriptor. From there, you can construct an `NSURL` use that to get the type (and, if you prefer, the dates, too).